# trying to get an empty object out of a request in mongoose to handle correctly the error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

i am sorry it's my first time posting a question on the stackoverflow but so far i haven't found any response despite my searches on google.
so i need to get an empty object out of a request with mongoose so i can handle more precisely the errors.
for the moment there are only two possible way to manage the requests.1: to get the value and send it back to the user or 2: in case if the query fails throwing an error in the .catch statement, and no matter what i receive as failed request it's always going through the .catch, but if a user sends a false id  so the i could send back a 404 status instead of letting the catch statement taking care of it.
so how am i supposed to handle it correctly?

1.so in the if statement i want when i request a false id the if statement gets executed but it never does and always goes down to the catch which is not that accurate to handling its specific errors!
my codes as follows:

```
app.get('/users/:id', async (req, res) => {

  const _id = req.params.id;
  try {

    const user = await User.findById(_id)
      if(!user){
           return res.status(400).send('not found');
       }
        res.send(user)

  }  catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(e)    
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what a false id would be but you can compare the id from the user query to the original _id to see if they match.

```js
const user = await User.findById(_id)
      if(user._id !== _id){
           return res.status(400).send('not found');
       }
       res.send(user)

}   catch (e) {
      res.status(500).send(e) 
    }
```

You can also add a check to see if the user object is empty.

```js
const user = await User.findById(_id)
      if(user._id !== _id || Object.entries(user).length === 0){
           return res.status(400).send('not found');
       }
       res.send(user)

}   catch (e) {
      res.status(500).send(e) 
    }
```

Object.entries() returns an array with the objects enumerable properties.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you so much for taking your time and answering me! i truly appreciated!